# Continue numbering PHP

Tags: php, database

I work on a page(.php) that show some information from databases(like article name,article author).I also have a pagination script that work good(the ideea of pagination script is when I press a link the url of the site goes to something like ?page=2)Now I try to numbering the records that I show form databases.But how can I do that?

Pagination script:

```
$per_pages = 6;
$nrofarticles_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM tbl_articles");
$nrdearticole = mysql_result($nrofarticles_query, 0);
$totalpages = ceil($nrdearticole/$per_pages);
$currentpagedisplay = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$firstpair = ($currentpagedisplay - 1) * $per_pages;
```

I echo record from database like so:

```
$articles_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_articles LIMIT $firstpair, $per_pages");
while($article = mysql_fetch_array(article_set)){
     echo $article['article_name'];
}
```

So I show 6 records from database on page change show the next 6 records or if is less than 6 show how many remained .How can I numbering the records like this:

```
?page=1
1 article_name1
2 article_name2
3 article_name3
....
6 article_name6

?page=2
keep going
7 article_name7
8 article_name8
.....
```

**EDIT**

I was thinking to something like

```
    <?php
    $nrofarticles = 0;
    $articles_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_articles LIMIT $firstpair,$per_pages");
    confirm($articles_set);
    while($article = mysql_fetch_array($articles_set)){
        $nrofarticles ++;
    }
    echo "<ul id=\"id\">";
        for($i = $firstpair+1; $i<=$nrofarticles * $currentpagedisplay; $i++){
                echo '<li class="nr_id">' .$i. '<sub>#</sub></li>';
        }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

It's works but only on first 2 page of 3 because I have 16 articles in total - so on last page $firstpair + 1 will be 13 and $nrofarticles * $currentpagedisplay will be 12(4(articles) * 3(page=3)).

Comment: $_GET['page']-1*6 should be the first index

Comment: @Jack: Check your calculation on the first page: 1*6 + 1 would be the first index, but would show "7"

Comment: possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907536/implementing-pagination-in-php

Comment: look top I came with an opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go use a framework. You'll get pagination (and all sorts of extras) for free.